# Can I connect two LAN's that have no static public IP through VPN server?

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-networking, vps, local-area-network

Can I connect two LAN's, for example main office and branch office LAN's that have no dedicated public IP (only connected to internet through cheap ISPs) through one VPN server that I installed in VPS (like Digital Ocean)?.
How do I do that if it's possible, and what software will I need?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. You can do this using OpenVPN among other VPN or tunneling software.  Ideally 
   1. Ensure That each office is on a different, non-overlapping subnet.
   2. Use routers that support acting as openvpn clients (dd-wrt can be flashed onto many Ethernet routers and does this)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider just hosting the VPN server at your main site and using a Dynamic DNS provider to publish/update the main site's IP address whenever it changes?  I do this for my offices and it works very well, and avoids putting stuff "in the cloud."

As an example, I use no-ip.com and their [DUC utility](https://www.noip.com/download?page=linux)